# Stack exchange app should keep votes highlighted

Tags: bug, android-app, down-votes, up-votes

After clicking it changes the number then changes the repective arrow back to a grey color.

Color should stay changed not revert back to grey.

Color should stay grey in situations where the user cannot vote validly for whatever reason.

Comment: I'm glad you posted this! It's been troubling me too, but I assumed it was by design. I'm looking forward to the fix!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep definitely a bug here.

It is pretty common in the Android app and will probably be fixed before 2016 so it doesn't become bothersome for other users and not become a 2016 resolution. When voting, the color should remain blue if you reload the page. If it doesn't then so something else is also buggy in the code.

Comment: Yay I found something useful =)